# ASP.NET MVC Import Excel File with OleDB

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, oledb

I get a problem to import excel file in ASP.NET MVC using OleDB, everything is well, but when I import file (.xls) with warning/alert like this

[image]

the system cannot read the file data.

This is my code:

```
private bool ImportToDB(string filepath)
        {
            try
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath);
                var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filepath);

                string conStr = "";
                switch (fileExtension)
                {
                    case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                        conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                        break;
                    case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                        conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                        break;
                }

                conStr = String.Format(conStr, filepath);
                OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
                OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
                OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

                //Get the name of First Sheet
                connExcel.Open();
                DataTable dtExcelSchema;
                dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                connExcel.Close();

                //Read Data from First Sheet
                connExcel.Open();
                cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
                oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
                oda.Fill(dt);
                connExcel.Close();


                Debug.WriteLine(fileExtension);
                Debug.WriteLine(dt.Rows.Count);


                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

the file is not corrupt, when I click Yes, the file showing all data.

Please anyone help me to solve this problem, How to read excel file with OleDB in ASP.NET ?

Thanks.

Comment: A suggestion: Open file the in a recent version Excel and save as the default file format xlsx I think and try to read that file.  The message essentially is saying that the xls file extension does not match the file contents.  xls is Excel 2003 or earlier (?).

Comment: We'd need to see your connection string (which appears to be the same for both file types incidentally). Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver will open both files so there's no need for the switch statement really.